# Issue in loop logic, testing for condition with for loop instead of while loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement

**Simply Looping until condition is met**

I have `Desired value = 10` and I make a loop that performs action means It makes calculations and runs the loop unless or until received value is within acceptable range.

```
value_desired = 10
```

`received Value = 5 ;` from code

Unless or until received value is with in acceptable range (10+1 = 11 ; 10-1 = 9) I should run the loop and perform the actions.

**Question:**

I have an issue in the `else` part

If my logic goes to the `else` part then I want my program to perform the tasks of else part and go to

```
J = out  + 4;
received_value_J = J;
```

then calculate a new value and perform the task unless it satisfies

```
if (ii == 1)
value_finalized =  received_value_J;
```

**I want to use `for loop` for this. Is it possible?**

```
value_desired = 10 
acceptable_limit_1 = value_desired + 1
acceptable_limit_2 = value_desired - 1
acceptable_limit_upper_range = [value_desired :0.01: acceptable_limit_1];
acceptable_limit_lower_range = [acceptable_limit_2 : 0.01 : value_desired ];

delta = 0.1;
out =  1 

J = out  + 4;
received_value_J = J;

ii =  (received_value_J >= acceptable_limit_lower_range(1) & ... 
       received_value_J <= acceptable_limit_upper_range(end) );

while ((ii ~= 1 ))   
    % Right now using this with while loop but i have commented it to explain the question
    % J = out  + 4;
    % received_value_J = J; 
    %  Range Limit    
    ii =  (received_value_J >= acceptable_limit_lower_range(1) & ...
           received_value_J <= acceptable_limit_upper_range(end) );

    difference_signal = (value_desired -  received_value_J );

    if (ii == 1)
        value_finalized =  received_value_J;    
    else (ii ~= 1)
        Add = delta*difference_signal;
        out =  received_value_J + Add ;    
    end
end
```

**Upgraded Explanation:**

I have performed tasks and received value after doing some stuffs.

Let’s suppose `received value` is `5`.

Now I will check this `received value (5)` with my `desired value` that is `10`.

If `5` is within range of `limits` means if `5 is greater than 9 and less than 11` then perform the task under  `If condition`

Otherwise perform the task under `Else condition` and update the value. In my example Update `out` and

`Go to`

```
   J = out + 4;
 received_value_J = J;
```

And find out new `received value`

In my example I will get `received_value_J = 5` first. I will check if it is in `range` of `9—11` if `not run else` and upgrade the value of `out` now it will become `9.500`.

As `9.500` is in `range of 9---11` so I will output this value.

I am using while loop for this which is working but problem with my original code is that after a lot of actions I will get my received value and after that I want to apply loop but in while loop I am performing all actions and comparing .

Comment: Sounds like you should use a while loop instead of For.

Comment: I am using while loop but problem is that in my original task the situation is a bit different. Is it possible that I will jump to    ` J = out  + 4;`
     `received_value_J = J;` command in start if I get else even for while loop

Comment: Try writing (not in code, by hand) a step by step list of what you want to start with, test for, and update. It's pretty unclear from your question what you're actually trying to *do* because you've just talked about how you want to hop around your existing code. "Testing if value is within range and updating it" is incredibly simple and broad, so we need to know what you want to achieve and why the existing code fails to do this.

Comment: Nothing appears to be affecting the ii variable. From what the code shows, only the out variable is affected.

Comment: Please have a look at the explanation now

Comment: If you uncomment statements written under while then values for ii will change

Comment: Your new explanation is basically the same as your previous explanation! You are still saying that you want to test if a value is within a range, and update it if not. You haven't explained *why* the current method isn't working, in the context of *what you're trying to achieve*. The last sentence is as close as you get, and it's massively vague...

Comment: @Wolfie, After reading the update to the post and your comment. It appears that received_value_J is updating. but for the life of me I cannot see where in the code it is changing. The only point I see where it changes is outside the while loop (unless everyone is referring to the commented code)

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Sorry, I assumed the code was working better than it is, and again say the question is unclear! You're right, neither `ii` or `received_value_J` change inside the loop. The fact that the OP said "the while loop is working" made me assume that they weren't stuck in an infinite loop! If you uncomment the 2nd and 3rd lines after the `while` start, then the values will change.

Comment: @Wolfie please  give me just few minutes i will explain it clearly. Sorry from my side for confusion . Sorry.